# OData V4 batch request 'Content-ID' was not present in the header

Tags: c#, odata, owin

Our OData endpoint is self-hosted(OWIN). For single request: creating, updating, patching and deleting everything works great, but the problem is when I send batch request.
I read a lot of articles, but still cannot solve the issue.
In OData documentation it says:
My question is: How can I set 'Content-ID' to batch request's header?

In endpoint Batch is enabled:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
var odataBatchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler(new HttpServer(config));
config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataApi", null, builder.GetEdmModel(), odataBatchHandler);
config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().MaxTop(null).Select();
appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
```

Here is the test:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void BatchRequestTest()
        {
            var odataAddress = "https://localhost:23170/Sample/Sample/OData/";
            var batchUrl = $"{odataAddress}$batch";
            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

            // Global batch request
            HttpRequestMessage batchRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, batchUrl);
            batchRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwdw==");
            MultipartContent batchContent = new MultipartContent("mixed", "batch_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

            // Third element: POST user creation
            // 1: a multipart content that represents the changeset container
            MultipartContent changeSet = new MultipartContent("mixed", "changeset_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            // 2: one request message object per post request
            HttpRequestMessage postRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{odataAddress}/SATeacher");
            postRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwdw==");

            postRequest.Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            // 3: one message content per corresponding post request
            HttpMessageContent postRequestContent = new HttpMessageContent(postRequest);
            postRequestContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            postRequestContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/http");
            postRequestContent.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
            // Add this POST content to the changeset
            changeSet.Add(postRequestContent);
            // Add the changeset to the batch content
            batchContent.Add(changeSet);

            // Here we go
            batchRequest.Content = batchContent;
            HttpResponseMessage response = http.SendAsync(batchRequest).Result;
            var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

Here is an exception:

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The header with name 'Content-ID' was not present in the header collection of the batch operation.","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.OData.ODataException","StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.OData.ODataBatchReader.CreateOperationRequestMessageImplementation()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.ODataBatchReader.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.ODataBatchReader.CreateOperationRequestMessage()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Batch.ODataBatchReaderExtensions.<ReadOperationInternalAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\Builds\\Eagle\\Eagle\\Framework\\Server\\OData\\Source\\System.Web.OData\\OData\\Batch\\ODataBatchReaderExtensions.cs:line 149\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Batch.ODataBatchReaderExtensions.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\Eagle\Eagle\Framework\Server\OData\Source\System.Web.OData\OData\Batch\ODataBatchReaderExtensions.cs:line 63\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Batch.DefaultODataBatchHandler.<ParseBatchRequestsAsync>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\\Builds\\Eagle\\Eagle\\Framework\\Server\\OData\\Source\\System.Web.OData\\OData\\Batch\\DefaultODataBatchHandler.cs:line 141\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Batch.DefaultODataBatchHandler.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Builds\Eagle\Eagle\Framework\Server\OData\Source\System.Web.OData\OData\Batch\DefaultODataBatchHandler.cs:line 44\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Batch.HttpBatchHandler.d__0.MoveNext()"}

Getting exception in line: HttpResponseMessage response = http.SendAsync(batchRequest).Result;

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think the error is descriptive. Can you try `postRequestContent.Headers.Add("Content-ID", "1");`,

More information,
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/

Comment: @JaliyaUdagedara trying now...

Comment: It may be easier to test it using the Microsoft.OData.Client. It has a method SaveChanges on the context that takes a parameter to allow batch requests.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose Sounds like good idea, I will try that

Comment: @JaliyaUdagedara your comment worked, It was easy, thanks. If you post an answer I will mark as correct answer

Comment: @Jamaxack, glad it helped. cheers mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is descriptive. Can you try, `postRequestContent.Headers.Add("Content-ID", "1");`,

More information,
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/